# SwiftUI SceneDelegate Issue

Tags: ios, swiftui

Within `SceneDelegate.swift` the following code is returning the error message **"Use of unresolved identifier 'ContentView'; did you mean 'ContentMode'?".**

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options 
connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

This error creates a failure in the program build. It's surprising since when I create a new project with the exact same `SceneDelegate.swift`, there is no issue with ContentView.

If I change ContentView to ContentMode it returns the error **'ContentMode' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers".**

Has anyone else had this issue? Just curious where I should start looking or what I have done wrong.

Comment: Please include your `ContentView` code as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured this one out. If anyone else is curious I changed the `ContentView.swift` file name but didn't update it in `SceneDelegate.swift`.

So if you change the `ContentView.swift` file to `BetterNameView.swift` you need to update the above code in `SceneDelegate.swift` from `ContentView()` to `BetterNameView()`